# How to map element of an array using pyDash in Python

Tags: python, lodash, pydash

I'm trying to chain and group than map an array using pydash

The idea is to recreate the same output of this lodash function :

```js
let chainedResult = (
    _.chain(oResult)
    // Group the elements of the result based on `CEMPLOYEE` property
    .groupBy("CCALENDAR_WEEK")
    // `key` is group's name (CEMPLOYEE), `value` is the array of objects
    .map((value, key) => ({
        WEEK: key,
        Capacity: value
    }))
).value();
```

So far, this is what I achieved

```
_.chain(empCapacity).group_by(lambda dt:dt["CCALENDAR_WEEK"]).value()
```

I'm stuck here, on how to make the mapping of the keys and value? How to do the below code in python using pydash?

```js
    .map((value, key) => ({
        WEEK: key,
        Capacity: value
    }))
```

**Desired Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just using `.map()`? [The docs say](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pydash.collections.map_):

> The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

Because that seems to be copied straight from the lodash docs. In python it's smart enough to check the signature of the "iteratee" (i.e. the function you pass to `.map()`), otherwise this would crash since in python you can't pass extra arguments to a function that is not expecting them.

So this works for me:

```py
from pydash import py_

my_entries = [
    {'name': 'barney', 'food': 'jelly'},
    {'name': 'bill', 'food': 'jelly'},
    {'name': 'buster', 'food': 'aubergine'},
]

(
    py_(my_entries)
    .group_by('food')
    .map(lambda value, key: (key, value))
).value()
```

Gives:

```py
[
    (
        'jelly',
        [
            {'name': 'barney', 'food': 'jelly'}, 
            {'name': 'bill', 'food': 'jelly'},
        ]
    ),
    (
        'aubergine', 
        [
            {'name': 'buster', 'food': 'aubergine'}
        ]
    )
]
```